# Skuid Hello World App not redirecting

Tags: visualforce, skuid

My home page for the force.com site is a visual force page that has this code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="skuid.Redirects"
    showHeader="true" sidebar="false" readonly="true" docType="html-5.0"
    action="{!IF(canUseSkuid,'',redirect)}" title="Edit">
    skuid:page page="HelloWorld" />
</apex:page>
```

The HelloWorld page shows a button 'Say Hello'. The action associated with the button is in a java snippet as follows:

```
acctRow = acctModel.getFirstRow();
alert("Hello " + acctRow.gandikotam__UserName__c);
window.location.href = "/apex/skuid__ui?page=SayHello&username=" + acctRow.gandikotam__UserName__c
```

I can see the alert but the page is not redirecting.

The URL I see in the browser is:

http://gandikotam-developer-edition.na35.force.com/customers/apex/skuid__ui?page=SayHello&userna...

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful to someone. I followed the instructions in this url to enable skuid to users and set up the license info:

http://help.skuid.com/m/11720/l/114236-build-force-com-sites-with-skuid